# Simplest way of arguing, square root equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm teaching a high school class in algebra and I'm attempting to remain as pure as possible in my arguments. A colleague has given his pupils the following equation:

$$
3=\sqrt{\frac{36}{x} + 6}
$$

I have taught my students that they are allowed to add/subtract, multiply by something nonzero and divide by something nonzero on both sides of an equation. How would I solve this only using these tools and the definition of the square root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State $x\ne0$ and $36/x+6\ge0$.

Multiply memberwise

$$9=\frac{36}x+6.$$

Subtract $6$

$$3=\frac{36}x.$$

Multiply by $x/3$

$$x=12.$$

Indeed, $12\ne0$ and $36/12+3\ge0$.

Comment: "Multiply memberwise" what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Neutronic: that should be obvious, no ?

Comment: Eh not really. english isnt my native language. Are you simply multiplying by 3 on both sides but since $3=\sqrt{\frac{36}{x}+6}$ you simply lift the square root? That was the step that I wanted to be very clear on. I have always seen it as applying the function $x^2$ on both sides.

Comment: If $a = b$ and $c = d$, then $ac = bd$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah thank you! Both of you! I see it clearly now.

Comment: @Neutronic By definition of square root, $a= \sqrt{b}$ if and only if $a^2=b$.

Comment: @Crostul Yes of course, I'm confusing it with going the other way. Thank you.